# Android fragment on windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

In our application we must use something like android fragment, but we are a begginers in programming for Windows Phone. We know that we can create a new object programmatically (like that: [Windows Phone 8 App Dynamically/programmatically create buttons in g grid/Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659219/windows-phone-8-app-dynamically-programmatically-create-buttons-in-g-grid-panel) ), but in our design it's a too difficult. We want to create one frame in xaml file, and later clone it many times, one under the other. It is possible in Windows Phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create User Control and included in any xaml page. [You can look here](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/why-and-how-to-create-a-user-control-in-windows-phone)